# Dynamically concatenate value in list if pattern matched

Tags: c#, list, linq, replace, pattern-matching

I have a list of string and an array of pattern

```
List<string> filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(dir, filter).ToList();

string[] prefixes = { "0.", "1.", "2.", "3.", "4.", "5.", "6.", "7.", "8.", "9." };
```

I want to replace value in filePaths for example like this:

```
"1. fileA" becomes "01. fileA"
"2. fileB" becomes "02. fileB"
"10. fileC" becomes "10. fileC" (since "10." is not in prefixes list)
```

Is there a way to do this without looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a prefixes list, you can just pad left with 0's using regex:

```
string input = "1. fileA";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, @"^\d+", m => m.Value.PadLeft(2, '0'));
```

To use on the whole list:

```
var filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(dir, filter).Select(s => Regex.Replace(s, @"^\d+", m => m.Value.PadLeft(2, '0'))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following, using `Select`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] prefixes = { "0.", "1.", "2.", "3.", "4.", "5.", "6.", "7.", "8.", "9." };
        var result = Directory.GetFiles(dir, filter).Select(s => prefixes.Contains(s.Substring(0, 2)) ? "0" + s : s).ToList();
    }
}
```

You enumerate the enumerable to check for the condition whether padding is needed, if so you pad, otherwise just return the original value.